# HTML Radio Button Customization with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

```html
<input type="radio" name="tshirt" value="1" ><label>T-Shirt-1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="tshirt" value="2" ><label>T-Shirt-2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="tshirt" value="3" ><label>T-Shirt-3</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="tshirt" value="4" ><label>No T-Shirt</label><br><br>


<input type="radio" name="shirt" value="1" ><label>Shirt-1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="shirt" value="2" ><label>Shirt-2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="shirt" value="3" ><label>No Shirt</label><br><br>

<hr>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="1" ><label>Shorts-1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="2" ><label>Shorts-2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="3" ><label>Shorts-3</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="4" ><label>Shorts-4</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="5" ><label>No Shorts</label><br><br>

<input type="radio" name="pants" value="1" ><label>Pants-1</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="pants" value="2" ><label>Pants-2</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="pants" value="3" ><label>No Pants</label><br><br>
```

So you are to chose T-shirt + Shirt and then Shorts + Pants on this sample store.

I want to make it so the customer has to pick at least a T-Shirt **OR** a Shirt **AND** at least a pair of Shorts **OR** Pants.

At least one item above the horizontal line and at least one item below the horizontal line has to be picked.

I am guessing I have to use jQuery to force this?

Comment: I'd suggest make the name to same in your `OR` logic, and add `checked` to anyone radio in each group to achieve the `AND` logic.

Comment: you don't **have** to use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a check when a submission happens. Here I have used a `submit` button and validate the inputs upon clicking it. Also I have changed the `name` attributes of the `NO` options so that those options won't affect the selection.

```js
var tshirtSelected = false;
var shirtSelected = false;
var shortSelected = false;
var pantSelected = false;

$("#myBtn").click(function() {

  $("input[name='tshirt']").each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      tshirtSelected = true;
    }
  });

  if (!tshirtSelected) {
    $("input[name='shirt']").each(function(i, obj) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        shirtSelected = true;
      }
    });
  }

  if (!(shirtSelected || tshirtSelected)) {
    alert("Please select a tshirt or a shirt!!!!");
  }

  $("input[name='shorts']").each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      shortSelected = true;
    }
  });

  if (!shortSelected) {
    $("input[name='pants']").each(function(i, obj) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        pantSelected = true;
      }
    });
  }

  if (!(shortSelected || pantSelected)) {
    alert("Please select a short or a pant!!!!");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="tshirt" value="1">
<label>T-Shirt-1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="tshirt" value="2">
<label>T-Shirt-2</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="tshirt" value="3">
<label>T-Shirt-3</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="no-tshirt" value="4">
<label>No T-Shirt</label>
<br>
<br>


<input type="radio" name="shirt" value="1">
<label>Shirt-1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="shirt" value="2">
<label>Shirt-2</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="no-shirt" value="3">
<label>No Shirt</label>
<br>
<br>

<hr>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="1">
<label>Shorts-1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="2">
<label>Shorts-2</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="3">
<label>Shorts-3</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="shorts" value="4">
<label>Shorts-4</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="no-shorts" value="5">
<label>No Shorts</label>
<br>
<br>

<input type="radio" name="pants" value="1">
<label>Pants-1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="pants" value="2">
<label>Pants-2</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="no-pants" value="3">
<label>No Pants</label>
<br>
<br>

<button id="myBtn">OK</button>
```

Comment: This looks like what I needed! I will give this a try.  Thank you!